# What is the best practice to insert an order consisting of multiple products into a SQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

On my website, users can put multiple products in their shopping cart and place an order. If the order would always consist of (for example) two products, I would create two attributes: `product1` and `product2`, both with a foreign key to the `products` table. The problem is, the amount of ordered products could be 1 to (theoretically) infinite.

What is the best way to insert this (possibly) infinite amount of ordered products into the database, while still maintaining the foreign key to `products` (so every ordered product is linked to the `products` table)?

Many thanks!

Comment: Create a new order_product table, storing orderId, productId, and informations about your ordered product (ie quantity).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a "many to many" relationship.  You essentially have two core entities:

- Product
- Order

Any Product can exist on multiple Orders, and any Order can have multiple Products.  So there needs to be a linking table between them to maintain this relationship.  Something as simple as this:

```
Product
--------
ID
Name
etc.

Order
--------
ID
CustomerID
etc.

OrderProduct
--------
OrderID
ProductID
Quantity
etc.
```

That third table contains the relationship between any given combination of a product and an order.  Information which is scoped to just the relationship and doesn't belong to the Order itself or the Product itself (such as the quantity of that Product for that Order) would go on that table.

You might even elevate this within the domain to be its own entity, something like this:

```
Product
--------
ID
Name
etc.

Order
--------
ID
CustomerID
etc.

OrderLineItem
--------
OrderID
ProductID
Quantity
etc.
```

All that's changed is the name, but naming is very important when defining the semantics of the business domain.  Now rather than just being a linking table, you can intuitively think of each OrderLineItem as child objects owned by the aggregate root of an Order.  Those child objects link to their parent (the Order), and each also links to a Product.